# What does "ground-covering gait" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does *ground-covering gait* mean, in the following paragraph?

> The Australian Terrier has an attractive ruff circling the neck with a crest of longer hair that enhances its intelligent and keen expression. This working terrier has a medium-boned, small, and sturdy body that is longer than it is tall. It can withstand harsh conditions and shows a **ground-covering gait**.

Answer (score 1):

***[Gait](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gait)*** refers to:

> - (Horse Training, Riding & Manège) (used esp of horses and dogs) the pattern of footsteps at various speeds, as the walk, trot, canter, etc, each pattern being distinguished by a particular rhythm and footfall.

***[cover (the) ground:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cover+ground)***

> To move across an area at an acceptable speed. *I think we can count on that racehorse to cover the ground.*

(Collins)

*Ground-covering gait* refers to the ability of the dog to run at a nice speed.